# CryptExportKey: how to export private key from PKCS#12 store?

Tags: winapi, cryptoapi

I need to export public and private RSA key from certificate, stored in `PKCS#12` format, on Windows.

I can open certificate store with `CertOpenStore()`, then find certificate with `CertFindCertificateInStore()` and acquire private key with `CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey()`.

It works Ok. Then I extract user key with `CryptGetUserKey()` It works too.

But `CryptExportKey()` with blob type `PRIVATEKEYBLOB` fails.
`CryptSetKeyParam()` with `KP_PERMISSIONS` and set permission `CRYPT_EXPORT` also fails.

How could I get all RSA key pair parameters in such case?

All examples use `CryptGenKey()` to create and THEN export key, but I need to export existing key pair to simple binary form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution: if use more specific `PFXImportCertStore()` to open PKCS#12 file instead of generic `CertOpenStore()` with `CERT_STORE_PROV_PKCS12` store provider, it accepts flag `CRYPT_EXPORTABLE` and key could be exported with `CryptExportKey()`.